# Numpy or Python for storing dicts

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to store multidimensional arrays which store something like python dicts.
At the moment it looks something like:

```
a = [[{'col':i,'row':j} for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]
```

I know that numpy is perfect if you want to do maths like working with matrices.
Things I would like to do fast:

- accessing by multidimensional indexes
- changing values using multidimensional indexes

And I don't know how to do that with normal Python lists. Cause something like

```
idx = [2,3]
print(a[idx])
```

doesn't exist, right?
It should outprint `{'row':2,'col':3}`

Thanks for your ideas and if numpy is the better option: How to create a two dimensional numpy array with values of something like a list type?
Is there a way to use `dtype=dict` ?

Comment: Take a look at Pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to have pandas more than 2 dimensional? Just found xarray which is quite new.

Comment: They have `Panel` which lets you have 3d data: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel. AFAIK there isn't support for more than 3 dimensions.

Comment: Yeah. I would like to be as flexible as possible.

Comment: @PaulPanzer no I want to access the value in row #3 and col #4 that way.

Comment: I updated my example and I don't see that (2,3) would work actually.
`list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Comment: Yeah I'm using the numpy version now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So your `a` is a list of lists:

```
In [656]: a = [[{'col':i,'row':j} for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]
In [657]: a
Out[657]: 
[[{'col': 0, 'row': 0},
  {'col': 1, 'row': 0},
  {'col': 2, 'row': 0},
  ....
In [658]: len(a)
Out[658]: 9
In [659]: a[2][3]
Out[659]: {'col': 3, 'row': 2}
```

Create an array from that:

```
In [660]: A=np.array(a, dtype=object)
In [661]: A.shape
Out[661]: (9, 9)
In [662]: A
Out[662]: 
array([[{'row': 0, 'col': 0}, {'row': 0, 'col': 1}, {'row': 0, 'col': 2},
        {'row': 0, 'col': 3}, {'row': 0, 'col': 4}, {'row': 0, 'col': 5},

In [663]: A[2,3]
Out[663]: {'col': 3, 'row': 2}
```

Not much difference between using `a[2][3]` and `A[2,3]` to access one dictionary.  Both contain pointers to the same dictionaries

```
In [664]: A[3,2]['value']=23    # add a key to one; see change in both places
In [666]: A[3,2]
Out[666]: {'col': 2, 'row': 3, 'value': 23}
In [667]: a[3][2]
Out[667]: {'col': 2, 'row': 3, 'value': 23}
```

I can reshape `A`,e.g. `A1=A.reshape(3,27)`, but that won't have any effect of the list nesting of `a`.  I could 'flatten' both with:

```
In [671]: aflat=list(itertools.chain(*a))   # new list, same dict
In [672]: len(aflat)
Out[672]: 81
In [673]: A.ravel().shape     # a view  A.flatten() for copy
Out[673]: (81,)
```

I could find the dict with the extra key with a list comprehension in either:

```
In [674]: [a for a in aflat if len(a)==3]
Out[674]: [{'col': 2, 'row': 3, 'value': 23}]
In [675]: [a for a in A.ravel() if len(a)==3]
Out[675]: [{'col': 2, 'row': 3, 'value': 23}]
```

Sometimes with object dtypes it is possible to perform limited amounts of array math, but that depends on the operation propagating down to objects.  I can't think of anything that would do that with dicts.

So for dictionary objects, there isn't much of a difference between using nested lists and object arrays.

---

The usual rules for array indexing apply:

```
In [676]: idx=[2,3]
In [677]: A[idx]   # (2,9) array of dict
Out[677]: 
array([[{'row': 2, 'col': 0}, ...{'row': 3, 'col': 8}]], dtype=object)
In [678]: A[tuple(idx)]     # 1 dict
Out[678]: {'col': 3, 'row': 2}
```

---

Structured array approach, using `fields` with the same names as your dictionary keys.

```
In [681]: dt=np.dtype([('col',int),('row',int)])
In [687]: S = np.array([[(i,j) for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)],dtype=dt)
In [688]: S.shape
Out[688]: (3, 3)
In [689]: S
Out[689]: 
array([[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)],
       [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)],
       [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]], 
      dtype=[('col', '<i4'), ('row', '<i4')])
In [691]: S[2,2]
Out[691]: (2, 2)
In [692]: S['col']
Out[692]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
In [694]: S[0,2]['row']
Out[694]: 0
```